# I need to find closest date in a rails app

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite, activerecord

I need to find the closest date to a given date using a rails named scope.

With MySql I could use DATEDIFF but I want to keep database agnosticism, following doesn't work with Sqlite:

```
named_scope :closest_to, lambda { |*args|
  date  = args.first
  count = args[1] || 1
  {:limit => count, :order => "ABS(DATEDIFF(hour, date_field, #{date.to_formatted_s :db}))"}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Postgres, you have to use `EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ())` to convert the interval to  seconds, since `ABS` only accepts numbers as arguments.

```
scope :order_by_closest_to, lambda { |date|
  {:order => %{ABS(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ('#{date.to_formatted_s(:db)}'::timestamp - some_timestamp_column))) asc} }
}
```

I don't think there's any database-agnostic way to do this query since the functions and casting differ between mysql, postgres and sqlite.

Answer (score 3):

Solved it like this:

```
named_scope :order_by_closest_to, lambda { |date|
  {:order => %{ABS(strftime('%s', "#{date.to_formatted_s(:db)}") - strftime('%s', value)) asc} }
}
```

Thus I can mix with other named scopes and limit the number of results so it won't iterate through all records.

Comment: Careful, this only works with SQLite AFAIK. For Postgresql, it would be something like: ABS(#{date.to_s(:db)} - value). More info here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.3/static/functions-formatting.html

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to use something along the lines of:

`:limit => count, :select => "*, abs(date('#{date.to_formatted_s :db}') - date('#{date_field}')) as date_diff", :order => "date_diff"`

Might be a bit database intensive though, as it has to calculate the `date_diff` field from all records.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL the above is commonly solved with something along the lines of:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE start_date = ( SELECT MAX(start_date) FROM my_table WHERE start_date <= '2011-02-18' )
```

That can be made to work for all databases that support subqueries (SQLite does not afaik). Great overview of "Point in Time" SQL here: http://www.orafaq.com/node/1834

Comment: Umm.. what if the supplied date is later than any existing dates?